# How do I add permission to a view or controller dynamically?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-roles

In all of my asp.net mvc projects up to this point, permissions to controllers are set by using a custom class based on the `[Authorize]` attribute.[image: For example:]

However, what if I wanted an administrator role who could grant access to views instead of going through the trouble of having to touch the controller to add/remove roles, re-complile, and push the changes to production. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Store the permissions in the database. Have your AuthLogAttribute query the database or preferably store a users permissions in session.

Comment: @Wheels73 the object is to authorize the views in the application without touching the code. You are suggesting that I query the database to get roles which I am doing for this application, but the question that I am asking is how to bind it to the view without typing code above the controller or view signature. How do I do so dynamically?

Comment: you need another level of abstraction.  Like a claim or permission. Tag all public controller actions with a permission.  you associate the permissions up to a role(s), but the check is done against the permission.  That way you can associate a user to a role or many roles and get all their permissions then check against that.

Comment: Hello.. Yes.. this is what i do. Access to various sections in my site are governed by an admin page that adds and removes access to Views by adding and removing a roles permissions. A user is then a member of a role and that role has access to the views.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Let me know if I've understood what you mean.. if not I'll delete the answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as discussed. Try the below.

in the controller as I'm sure you're aware.

```
[PermissionsFilter("CanAccessMyView")]
public ActionResult ReturnMyView () 
{
   //etc..
}
```

Then, in your custom class

```
 public class PermissionsFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private readonly PermissionManager _permissionsManager;

        public PermissionsFilter(string permissionName)
        {
            _permissionName = permissionName;
            _permissionsManager = new PermissionServiceManager();
        }

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!_permissionServiceManager.CanAccessPermission(_permissionName))
            {
                var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
                var url = urlHelper.Action("Unauthorised", "Home");
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);
            }
        }
    }
```

Where the permissions manager is querying the database or perhaps session info to see if the user user has access.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I see where you are going with this...I am going to test it

Comment: OK... Perhaps build up a list of user permissions in session when the user logs on to avoid db trips if required. Then either add and remove to the db and session at the same time or stipulate that permission changes require a new session. The permissions manager will need to know the user it is dealing with or perhaps have the manger access the current user context. I've actually got to go.. so good luck.